# Sublime Text: Do not save readonly files on focus lost

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

Some files may be readonly, and I become annoying modal windows after losing focus.
Is it possible to disable the "save_on_focus_lost" option only for readonly files?

Comment: yes, but you'll need to write a plugin for it. What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows and (sometimes MAC)